Deriving the Logit Choice Probability from a Random Utility Model
Suppose we have a random utility model given by $u_{ij}=\delta_j + \varepsilon_{ij}$.
This model specifies the utility that consumer $i$ receives by choosing product $j$. We can interpret $\delta_j$ as the mean utility of product $j$ and $\varepsilon_{ij}$ as an individual taste shock. We assume $\varepsilon_{ij}$ is i.i.d (across consumers and products) Type 1 Extreme Value. For reference in what follows, the density of $\varepsilon_{ij}$ is given by $ f(\varepsilon_{ij})=e^{-\varepsilon_{ij}}e^{-e^{-\varepsilon_{ij}}}$, while the CDF is $F(\varepsilon_{ij})=e^{-e^{-\varepsilon_{ij}}}$.
Lets assume that there are a total of $J+1$ products, with product $0$ being the "outside good" and the mean utility of it is normalized to $\delta_0=0$ so that $u_{i0}=\varepsilon_{i0}$.
I am interested in deriving the probability that consumer $i$ chooses product $j$, conditional on observing the mean utility of each product:
$\mathbb{P}({\text{ \{ i chooses product} \; j \; \}| \; \boldsymbol{\delta}  })=\mathbb{P}( \{ u_{ij} \geq u_{ik}  \; \forall k \neq j \; \} | \; \boldsymbol{\delta}) = \mathbb{P}( \{ \delta_j + \varepsilon_{ij} \geq \delta_k + \varepsilon_{ik} \; \forall k \neq j \; \} | \; \boldsymbol{\delta})$
\begin{align*}
    \mathbb{P}({\text{ \{ i chooses product} \; j \; \} | \; \boldsymbol{\delta}  })=\mathbb{P}( \{ \varepsilon_{ik} - \varepsilon_{ij} \leq \delta_j - \delta_k  \; \forall k \neq j \; \} | \; \boldsymbol{\delta})= \mathbb{P}( \{ \varepsilon_{ik} \leq \varepsilon_{ij} + \delta_j - \delta_k \; \forall k \neq j \} \mid \boldsymbol{\delta} )
\end{align*}
The usual argument here is that we assume $\varepsilon_{ij}$ is fixed. Then given that the taste shocks for consumer $i$ are independent, we can rewrite the probability as:
$\mathbb{P}({\text{ \{ i chooses product} \; j \; \}| \; \boldsymbol{\delta} , \varepsilon_{ij}  })=\prod_{k \neq j}^{J} \mathbb{P}( \{ \varepsilon_{ik} \leq \varepsilon_{ij} + \delta_j - \delta_k \; \forall k \neq j \} \mid \boldsymbol{\delta} )$
Using the CDF of the taste shocks this can be written as:
$\mathbb{P}({\text{ \{ i chooses product} \; j \; \}| \; \boldsymbol{\delta} , \varepsilon_{ij}  })= \prod_{\substack{k=0 \\ k \neq j}}^{J} F(\varepsilon_{ij} + \delta_j - \delta_k) = \prod_{\substack{k=0 \\ k \neq j}}^{J} e^{-e^{-(\varepsilon_{ij}+\delta_j - \delta_k)}} $.
Then in order find the choice probability we would actually have to integrate over all values of $\varepsilon_{ij}$ :
\begin{align*}
    \mathbb{P}(\text{ \{ i chooses product } j \} \mid \boldsymbol{\delta}) &= \int\limits_{\varepsilon_{ij}=-\infty}^{+\infty} \left( \prod_{\substack{k=0 \\ k \neq j}}^{J} e^{-e^{-(\varepsilon_{ij}+\delta_j - \delta_k)}} \right) e^{-\varepsilon_{ij}}e^{-e^{-\varepsilon_{ij}}} \, d\varepsilon_{ij} \quad (1)
\end{align*}.
With some extra steps (that can be found in Chapter 3 of Train's Book) we can reach the expression:
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{P}(\text{ \{ i chooses product } j \} \mid \boldsymbol{\delta}) &= \frac{e^{\delta_j}}{ \displaystyle 1 + \sum_{k=1}^{J} e^{\delta_k}} \quad (2)
\end{align*}
Here is where my question actually starts. Going from Equation (1) to Equation (2) is clear to me. I would however like to reach Equation (1) in a different way, and I wonder if this is correct.
For clarity, I will assume that there are only 3 products: the outside option 0, and products 1 & 2. The probability of choosing product 1 is:
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{P}(\text{ \{ i chooses product } 1 \} \mid \boldsymbol{\delta}) &= \mathbb{P}((\varepsilon_{i0} \leq \varepsilon_{i1} + \delta_1) \cap (\varepsilon_{i2} \leq \varepsilon_{i1} + \delta_1 - \delta_2) \mid \boldsymbol{\delta})
\end{align*}
Now let $\tilde{f}(\varepsilon_{i0} , \varepsilon_{i1},\varepsilon_{i2})$ be the joint density of $\boldsymbol{\varepsilon}=(\varepsilon_{i0}, \varepsilon_{i1},\varepsilon_{i2}) $.
Notice that since $\varepsilon_{ik} \perp \varepsilon_{im} \; \forall k \neq m $, then the joint density is the product of the marginal densities:
\begin{align*}
    \tilde{f}(\varepsilon_{i0} , \varepsilon_{i1},\varepsilon_{i2})= \prod_{k=0}^{2} f(\varepsilon_{ik})= \prod_{k=0}^{2} e^{-\varepsilon_{ik}}e^{-e^{-\varepsilon_{ik}}}
\end{align*}
Using the above, the probability of $i$ choosing product $1$ is:
\begin{align*}
   \mathbb{P}(\text{ \{ i chooses product } 1 \} \mid \boldsymbol{\delta}) &= \int\limits_{\varepsilon_{i1}=-\infty}^{+\infty} \int\limits_{\varepsilon_{i0}=-\infty}^{\varepsilon_{i1} + \delta_1} \int\limits_{\varepsilon_{i2}=-\infty}^{\varepsilon_{i1} + \delta_1 - \delta_2} \tilde{f}(\varepsilon_{i0} , \varepsilon_{i1}, \varepsilon_{i2}) \, d\varepsilon_{i2} d\varepsilon_{i0} d\varepsilon_{i1}
\end{align*}
\begin{align*}
   \mathbb{P}(\text{ \{ i chooses product } 1 \} \mid \boldsymbol{\delta}) &= \int\limits_{\varepsilon_{i1}=-\infty}^{+\infty} \int\limits_{\varepsilon_{i0}=-\infty}^{\varepsilon_{i1} + \delta_1} \int\limits_{\varepsilon_{i2}=-\infty}^{\varepsilon_{i1} + \delta_1 - \delta_2} \prod_{k=0}^{2} f(\varepsilon_{ik}) d\varepsilon_{i2} d\varepsilon_{i0} d\varepsilon_{i1}
\end{align*}
\begin{align*}
   \mathbb{P}(\text{ \{ i chooses product } 1 \} \mid \boldsymbol{\delta}) &= \int\limits_{\varepsilon_{i1}=-\infty}^{+\infty} f(\varepsilon_{i1}) \int\limits_{\varepsilon_{i0}=-\infty}^{\varepsilon_{i1} + \delta_1} f(\varepsilon_{i0}) \int\limits_{\varepsilon_{i2}=-\infty}^{\varepsilon_{i1} + \delta_1 - \delta_2} f(\varepsilon_{i2}) d\varepsilon_{i2} d\varepsilon_{i0} d\varepsilon_{i1}
\end{align*}
Therefore the above multi-dimensional integral reduces to:
\begin{align*}
    \mathbb{P}(\text{ \{ i chooses product } 1 \} \mid \boldsymbol{\delta}) &= \int\limits_{\varepsilon_{i1}=-\infty}^{+\infty} \left(\prod_{\substack{k=0 \\ k \neq 1}}^{2} F(\varepsilon_{i1} + \delta_1 - \delta_k) \right) f(\varepsilon_{i1}) \, d\varepsilon_{i1} \quad (3)
\end{align*}
Equation (3) is the equivalent of Equation (1) when $ j \in \{0,1,2\}$. From there on, I can do the standard steps to reach Equation (2). Is there a logical jump in my derivation or do most textbooks just use the first way to derive it?
